# Filtering sales as per the top 10 customers in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to filter the monthly sales as per the top 10 customers' sales in power bi. Can any one help me with that DAX.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at the RANKX function, I'm sure this will do what you need, have a look over at [SQLBI](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/use-of-rankx-in-power-bi-measures/) I can't offer anything more specific as your request is pretty general. Post a more specific question if you run into trouble!